# Can I open an UML-diagram without having a project?

Tags: hibernate, intellij-idea, uml

I have an UML-file, but I don't have a project. It was generated in Intelliji IDEA with Hibernate (just know that word by guy that made this file). Inside looks like it has links to the local paths (`file://D:/projects/...name.java`) and it makes me think that nothing can help me.

Is it possible to open it? If so, how?
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: No, IntelliJ IDEA requires a project to be able to use most of the features.